# Correct way to handle @Version column and AJAX calls with Hibernate/Spring Forms

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using spring forms to bind a domain object to a view.

I have added the following binding to the jsp page

```
<sf:hidden id="myObject-id" path="myObject.version"/>
```

version is a hibernate versioning field

```
@Version
@Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)
public long getVersion() {
    return version;
}
```

The problem is that I have a save button that allows the user to save the form via json.  the controller will execute:

```
myObjectService.saveOrUpdate(myObject);
```

The problem here is that this will work the first time because the correct `version` field is being used.  From now on all saves will fail with StaleObjectStateException.

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you updating the `hidden` field with the new `VersionId` ?

Comment: no I am not, in fact I would like a solution that does not use the version field in the view if possible (is is normal practice to update the version manually via javascript?)

Comment: Go through this link, It may help you in getting rid of the hidden `versionId` field - http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/hibernate-versioning-example-hibernate-versioning-of-objects/

Comment: @Niranja That does not help